# Can a ouliner operator be placed in an custom Panel

Tags: data-blocks, panel

```
bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
```

to put it onto a button into a custom panel-
but that button is grayed out...

this is how it looks like:

```
import bpy 



#--------------------------------------------------------------------

class CleanUnusedMaterials(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the TOOLS window"""
    bl_label = "CleanUnusedMaterials"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_CLEANUNUSEDMATERIALS"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("view3d.clean_material_slots")
        row.operator("outliner.orphans_purge")


#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():

    bpy.utils.register_class(CleanUnusedMaterials)


def unregister():

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CleanUnusedMaterials)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is it because its an outliner operator?
or am i missing something?

Comment: batFINGER- did you change anything in the code?